# Replication time in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have been trying to do some tests on ZooKeeper cluster. I was wondering if anyone knows how much time does ZooKeeper take for replicating the data to its followers. Or if there was a way to measure this? I have been looking at log files but they don't seem to help me much and my eyes hurt trying to deduce this from reading the logs.

Also, do you have any recommendations on using a monitoring service that can show me continuous real time output of what's happening in the service?

In one of my test cases, I create 200 znodes with varying length of values (32 bytes, 64, 128...) And I notice anything greater than 512 bytes takes less time than the ones less than 512 bytes. I would love to know how the replication process in zookeeper works.

Thanks,
Ganesh